# Select two columns in one column

Tags: mysql

I have to columns in a table which are nom and prenom.

I want to select the `nom` column and the `prenom` column as one result for exemple :

```
|nom | prenom|  
|----+-------+
|AA  | BB    |
```

I want when I select these two columns to display it as one columnn :

```
|nom et prénom |
+--------------+
|AA BB         |
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `CONCAT` for that:

```
SELECT CONCAT(nom, ' ', prenom)
FROM YourTable
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40613/1)

Answer (score 0):

CONCAT(str1,str2,...)

> Returns the string that results from concatenating the arguments. May
>   have one or more arguments. If all arguments are nonbinary strings,
>   the result is a nonbinary string. If the arguments include any binary
>   strings, the result is a binary string. A numeric argument is
>   converted to its equivalent binary string form; if you want to avoid
>   that, you can use an explicit type cast

You can use `CONCAT` for that purpose

```
SELECT CONCAT(nom, ' ', prenom) FROM YourTable
```

[**CONCAT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)